# Joining three tables in SQL, Inner join does not work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

We have three tables, `document`,`department` and `contact`.

All the tables are linked by an 'id' column. I want the result as follows

```
     firstname  lastname  address upload_date  department_name
```

The below query fetches the first four columns

```
  SELECT contact.firstname, contact.lastname,contact.address ,
  document.upload_date
  FROM contact
  JOIN document 
  ON document.id= contact.id
  AND  contact.status = 1 
  AND document.defaultdoc=1
```

So it's an inner join.

But to fetch the last column, the `department_name` I added a similar join with `contact.deptId=department.id`, but the query returns zero results. Anything wrong ?

Comment: Without actual tables structure we can just guess. It could be you use wrong ids (primary key in the document instead of foreign key)

Comment: You're joining `document 1` to `contact 1`, which is unlikely to be correct.  Does the `document` table have a `contact_id` field?  Or is there a linking table with `contact_id` and `document_id`?  You may need to give us all the field names in each of those three tables.  Or ask someone in your organisation who understands which fields you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

if you add

```
JOIN department 
ON contact.deptId=department.id
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If all deptId's exist in its master table department then you can use below query:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname,c.address ,
  doc.upload_date, d.department_name
  FROM contact as c
  JOIN document as doc
  ON doc.id= c.id
  AND  c.status = 1 
  AND doc.defaultdoc=1
  JOIN department as d
  on c.deptId=d.id;
```

But if deptid updated in contact table does not exist in department table (which should not be if you want referential integrity in your db), then you can use below query:

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname,c.address ,
  doc.upload_date, d.department_name
  FROM contact as c
  JOIN document as doc
  ON doc.id= c.id
  AND  c.status = 1 
  AND doc.defaultdoc=1
  LEFT JOIN department as d
  on c.deptId=d.id;
```

If both don't work then show your table data and structure.